# Method set/add is not a function sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables, orders, products and the pivot table, order_products, the table orders and products have i relation many to many, but when i try to use the method

```
order.addProduts()
```

Don't work, return the error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Order.addProducts is not a function
```

But i had verify my model of products and orders, the relation its ok, i don't see anything wrong

my model and my controller when i try to use the method:

```
class Products extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            price: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            description: DataTypes.STRING
        },{
            sequelize
        })
        
    }
    static associate(models){
        this.belongsToMany(models.Orders, {as: 'order_product', foreignKey: 'product_id', through: 'order_products'})
    }
}
module.exports = Products;


class Orders extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            street: DataTypes.STRING,
            phonenumber: DataTypes.STRING,
            number: DataTypes.STRING,
            reference: DataTypes.TEXT,
            note: DataTypes.TEXT,
         

        }, {
            sequelize,
        })
    }
    static associate(models){
        this.belongsToMany(models.Products, {as: 'product_order', foreignKey: 'order_id', through: 'order_products'})
    }

}
```

My controller

```
async store (req, res){
        const {name, phonenumber, street, number, reference, note, value_subtotal, value_delivery, value_total, products} = req.body;
        if(!(name|| phonenumber || value_subtotal || value_total))return res.status(406).send({message: 'missing data!'})
        if((value_total|| value_subtotal) <= 0)return res.status(406).send({message: "total value or subtotal value can't be 0 or less than"})

        //console.log(products)
        const Order = await Orders.create({
            name, 
            phonenumber, 
            street,
            number,
            reference,
            note,
            value_subtotal,
            value_delivery,
            value_total
        })
        await Order.addProducts(products)
        return res.status(201).json(Order);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
not confirmend but i think you are using Order.addProducts() instead of order.addProduts();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

You can try to achieve the same behaviour by doing this:

```js
Order.create({
   name,
   Product: {...}
},{
   include: Product
})
```

Or try examples from srequlize docs: [Creating with associations](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/associations.html)